# Returns Each Item Instead Of "Array" Json MVC Web Api .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, json, serialization

Hi im trying to create Json data which returns an array but when i serialize List  it returns each item. I would like to see --

ArrayName : [{"HaberID":5518,"Tarih":"Jan  6 2.....

Here is my method in controller

```
 public ActionResult GetHaber()
        {
            MemberDAL dal = new MemberDAL();

            return Json(dal.GetMembers(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My Result;

[{"HaberID":5518,"Tarih":"Jan  6 2014 10:30AM","Baslik":"Dolar haftaya rekorla başladı","Slogan":"Dolar kuru rekor kırmaya devam ediyor. Dolar/TL sabah saatlerin 2,19 seviyesini aşarak tarihinin en yüksek seviyesine çıktı. Euro/TL kuru ise 2,9730 seviyesinden işlem görüyor. BIST-100 saat 10:00 itibariyle yüzde 0,5 etc.......................]

Comment: that is what you gave it. you might need a view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could serialize an anonymous type that contains your array instead:

```
public ActionResult GetHaber()
{
    MemberDAL dal = new MemberDAL();

    return Json(
        new
        {
            ArrayName: dal.GetMembers()
        }, 
        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed return as string and it worked.

```
public string GetHaber()
    {
        return ("{\n \"ArrayName\": "  + new MemberDAL().GetMembers()) + "\n}";
    }
```

GetMembers returns Json instead of List and i added what i need.